Flutter FCM Notification Works on Android but Fails on iOS with 400 Error (DioException)
I’m using Flutter to send push notifications via Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) using the HTTP v1 API. The notification works fine on Android, but I’m getting a 400 (bad request) error when sending to iOS devices. Below is the code I’m using:
Future\<void\> sendNotificationF() async {
try {
String? accessToken = await CommonMethods.getAccessToken();
final \_dio = Dio();

    // Set FCM HTTP v1 headers
    _dio.options.headers = <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
    };
    
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    String? token = Platform.isAndroid
        ? await messaging.getToken()
        : await messaging.getAPNSToken();
    
    if (token == null) {
      print("Error: Could not retrieve FCM token.");
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Error: Could not retrieve FCM token.",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      return;
    }
    
    var data = {
      "message": {
        "token": token,
        "data": {
          "title": "Hello",
          "message": "This is a notification message.",
          "body": "This is the body content.",
          "sound": "notification_chat",
        },
        "notification": {
          "title": "Hello",
          "body": "This is the notification body.",
        },
        "android": {
          "priority": "high",
          "notification": {
            "sound": "notification_chat", // Custom sound for Android
            "channel_id": "astrosane",
          },
        },
        "apns": {
          "payload": {
            "aps": {
              "sound": "notification_chat", // Custom sound for iOS
            },
          },
        },
      }
    };
    
    final response = await _dio.post(
      'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-ID/messages:send',
      data: jsonEncode(data),
    );
    
    print("Notification sent successfully!");

} on DioError catch (e) {
print("Notification error: $e");
Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.response?.data.toString() ?? "An error occurred", toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
}

Error
{error: {code: 400, message: The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token, status: INVALID_ARGUMENT, details: [{@type: type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError, errorCode: INVALID_ARGUMENT}]}
